# QT GridLayout with QPushButton

Tags: qt

I emulate in my code the ribbon style. For this I use also QGridLayout.
But I have a Problem.

| colspan 3 QLineEdit|

|QLabel |QLineEdit |QLabel |QLineEdit |QLabel |QLineEdit|

|QLabel |QComboBox |QLabel |QLineEdit |

This looks like:
[image: Perfect]

Now I need a QPushButton on the right hand side of the edit, so I try to add the button to the Grid.

```
myBootGridLayout->addWidget(btnSelBootImagePath,0,3);
```

I also tried 0,4 to make sure it is not a cell problem.

| colspan 3 QLineEdit| QPushButton|

|QLabel |QLineEdit |QLabel |QLineEdit |QLabel |QLineEdit|

|QLabel |QComboBox |QLabel |QLineEdit |

But after the QPushButton was added, the Grid looks like:

[image: Damaged]

It looks like that the QPushButton kills the GRidLayout. I tried to set the button to fixed hight 16 and it do not help. Button is very wrong placed.

[image: Wrong Position]

Finally I tried to set with CSS the margin and padding of the button to 0. Also do not work.

Is there a solution for this available? My goal is to have the QLineEdit and on the right hand a button to select a file.Both with the same height.

I have a couple of GRidLayouts there in my ui and all work fine, just the one with QPushButton not.

The complete Grid code is:

```
     QGridLayout *myBootGridLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
     QWidget * wdgBootFeatues = new QWidget(this);


     imagePathBootEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
     imagePathBootEdit->setReadOnly(true);
     imagePathBootEdit->setMaximumWidth(300);
     imagePathBootEdit->setMinimumWidth(300);
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(imagePathBootEdit,0,0,1,3);

        //Problem
         QPushButton *btnSelBootImagePath = new QPushButton(this);

         btnSelBootImagePath->setText(tr("..."));
         //btnSelBootImagePath->setMinimumWidth(16);
         btnSelBootImagePath->setMaximumWidth(32);
         //btnSelBootImagePath->setMinimumHeight(16);
         btnSelBootImagePath->setMaximumHeight(16);
         //connect(btnSelBootImagePath, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(clickedSelBootImagePath()));
         //btnSelBootImagePath->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{padding:0px;margin:0px;}");
         myBootGridLayout->addWidget(btnSelBootImagePath,0,3);




     QLabel *labelDeveloperID = new QLabel(this);
     labelDeveloperID->setText(tr("Developer ID:"));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(labelDeveloperID,1,0);
     developerIDBootEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
     developerIDBootEdit->setMinimumWidth(100);
     developerIDBootEdit->setMaximumWidth(100);
     //connect(developerIDBootEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(bootDeveloperIDchanged(QString)));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(developerIDBootEdit,1,1);

     QLabel *labelSectos = new QLabel(this);
     labelSectos->setText(tr("Sectors:"));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(labelSectos,1,2);
     sectorsBootEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
     sectorsBootEdit->setMinimumWidth(80);
     sectorsBootEdit->setMaximumWidth(80);
     //connect(sectorsBootEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(bootSectorschanged(QString)));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(sectorsBootEdit,1,3);

     QLabel *labelLoadSegment = new QLabel(this);
     labelLoadSegment->setText(tr("Load segment:"));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(labelLoadSegment,1,4);
     loadSegmentBootEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
     loadSegmentBootEdit->setMinimumWidth(80);
     loadSegmentBootEdit->setMaximumWidth(80);
     //connect(edBootLoadSegment,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(bootLoadSegmentchanged(QString)));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(loadSegmentBootEdit,1,5);

     QLabel *labelEmulation = new QLabel(this);
     labelEmulation->setText(tr("Emulation Type:"));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(labelEmulation,2,0);
     emulationTypeBootCombo = new QComboBox();
     emulationTypeBootCombo->setMinimumWidth(100);
     emulationTypeBootCombo->setMaximumWidth(100);
     emulationTypeBootCombo->addItem(tr("No emulaton (NT/2000/XP)"));
     emulationTypeBootCombo->addItem(tr("Floppy 1.2MB"));
     emulationTypeBootCombo->addItem(tr("Floppy 1.44MB (95/98/ME)"));
     emulationTypeBootCombo->addItem(tr("Floppy 2.88MB"));
     emulationTypeBootCombo->addItem(tr("Hard Disk"));
     //connect(emulationTypeBootCombo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(bootEmulationTypeChanged(int)));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(emulationTypeBootCombo,2,1);

     QLabel *labelPlatfom = new QLabel(this);
     labelPlatfom->setText(tr("Platform:"));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(labelPlatfom,2,2);
     platformBootCombo = new QComboBox();
     platformBootCombo->setMinimumWidth(100);
     platformBootCombo->setMaximumWidth(100);
     platformBootCombo->addItem(tr("x86 - 32"));
     platformBootCombo->addItem(tr("x86 - 64"));
     platformBootCombo->addItem(tr("PowerPC"));
     platformBootCombo->addItem(tr("MAC"));
     //connect(platformBootCombo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(bootPlatformChanged(int)));
     myBootGridLayout->addWidget(platformBootCombo,2,3);

//Added for testing button problem
     myBootGridLayout->setRowMinimumHeight(0,25);
     myBootGridLayout->setRowMinimumHeight(1,25);
     myBootGridLayout->setRowMinimumHeight(2,25);
     myBootGridLayout->setContentsMargins(3,0,0,0);

//Add Lyout to ui
     wdgBootFeatues->setLayout(myBootGridLayout);
     wdgBootFeatues->setFixedHeight(80);
     ui->ribbonTabWidget->addWidgetGroup("Boot Disc", "El-Torito", wdgBootFeatues);
```

Comment: btnSelBootImagePath->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding,
                    QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);

Comment: Great, many thanks!!!!

Comment: welcome ) Happy to help